# packrat cannot sync package versions with CRAN

Tags: r, rstudio, packrat

I installed `packrat` and tried to initialize it in my project directory, which uses R 3.2.5:

```
> packrat::init("~/ope_orx")
```

I get the complete list of packages and then `packrat` tries to fetch sources and I get this type of error for almost all packages:

```
Fetching sources for BH (1.62.0-1) ... Warning in getSourceForPkgRecord(pkgRecord, sourceDir, availablePkgs, repos) :
Package version '%s' is newer than the latest version reported by CRAN ('%s') -- packrat may be unable to retrieve package sources.
FAILED
```

I checked on one of the CRAN mirrors and the current version of `BH` is the same as the installed version. Any ideas what might be wrong here?

I'm also willing to use/try another R package management tool - any suggestions?

Comment: You may have manage to install package compile under R 3.3 in your library for R 3.2, or the `.libPaths()` is wrong.

Comment: `.libPaths()` is correctly set. I installed the packages via `install.packages()` command - I assume everything should be fine regarding the R versions... Is there a fundamental difference regarding package installations between R 3.3 and 3.2 that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Packages compiled under one major version may not run under another major version.  But it was only a warning. There might be success in loading and running.

Comment: @42- unfortunately it doesn't. It fails right after that warning (added that line to the question)

Comment: Then you need to get the correct source package from the archives and reinstall on your outdated version of R.